# get one field from elasticsearch by spring data

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

I have a ES Document like this

```
class User {
    String name;
    String describe;
    List<String> items;
}
```

I'm using spring data to talk to ES by the Repository interface

```
interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, String> {
}
```

Now I need to build a rest interface which responses a JSON-format data like this

```
{"name": String, "firstItem": String}
```

Because the `describe` and `items` in `User` is very big, it's very expensive to retrieve all field from the ES.

I know the ES have a feature named "Response Filtering" which can fit my requirement, but I don't find a way to using it in Spring Data.

How to do this in spring data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a mix of [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) (for not **retrieving** heavy fields) and [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_response_filtering) (for not **returning** heavy fields). However, the latter is not supported in Spring Data ES (yet)

For the former, you can leverage `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` and specify a `FetchSourceFilter` that will only retrieve the fields you need. The latter is not supported yet in Spring Data ES. What you can do is to create another field named `firstItem` in which you'd store the first element of `items` so that you can return it for this query.

```
private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

String[] includes = new String[]{"name", "firstItem"};
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
    .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceBuilder(includes, null))
    .build();

Page<User> userPage =
    elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery, User.class);
```

Comment: The `firstItem` isn't a field name. I meant the first item of `items`. I tried to use `items[0]`, but it seems not work. does ES support it?

Comment: That's what I said, you should create another field named `firstItem` which will contain the same value as `items[0]`

Comment: what's the difference between retrieving a field and returning a filed?  Retrieve and return sound like synonyms for the same thing to me

Comment: Elastic will return the fields you specify but then Spring Data will still map it to the same entity model meaning you will have a the missing fields marked as null...which is a mess since you propably have fields with legit null values, so you wont be able to differentiate...