# Make ElasticsearchRepository return specific fields in Page?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

How to specify the fields to return in the book object?

```java
interface BookRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Book, String> {

    Page<Book> findByName(String name,Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: You have to write query @Query("SELECT b.column1, b.column2, ...from  Book b where b.name = :name")

Comment: but elasticSearch don't accept this format for query.

Comment: please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461623/get-one-field-from-elasticsearch-by-spring-data/39461862#39461862 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55177417/getting-only-selected-column-in-spring-data-elastic-search-repository

Comment: that was it Lemmy.