# Elastic search query for spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'd like to put this query into spring boot repository:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "_source": 
        "data.results.id"
}
```

but I don't know how.

```
@Repository

public interface HeroRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ES, String>{
    @Query(????????????????????????????)
    Iterable<ES> findAllId();
}
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: You can refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461623/get-one-field-from-elasticsearch-by-spring-data