# How to model repository interfaces in spring-data-elasticsearch for exclusive save & read access for managing data in an index

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I would like to persist only Foo or Bar or Baz attributes in the index "users". Since the user interface has different sections for representing Foo, Bar, Baz attributes it would be preferable to save only those attributes which have changed. How to model the REST controller interface and the corresponding Elasticsearch queries for saving and retrieving.

```
@Document(indexName = "users", shards = 1, versionType = VersionType.INTERNAL, createIndex = true)
@TypeAlias("user")
@Data
@Builder
public class User implements Persistable<Long> {
    @Id private Long id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    private Foo foo;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    private Bar bar;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    private Baz baz;

}
```

I would like to have the API interfaces, something like as there would be separate screens to update user specific sub-sections. Is this a correct approach

```
PUT /users/<user.id>/foo (contains Foo + PK)
PUT /users/<user.id>/bar
PUT /users/<user.id>/baz
```

Comment: You can retrieve and update the specific object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461623/get-one-field-from-elasticsearch-by-spring-data